# Using a list to multiply a value?

Tags: python, list

```
n1 = 20*values[0]
n2 = 100*values[1]
print(n1,"\n",n2)
```

I've basically got a list above this, with a few values, only if I would have

currently if i have 3 in the first value and 7 in the second, 3 would show up 20 times, and 7 would show up 100 times,
however i would like it to be just multiplied.

Is there any way to do this without importing anything?

--edited again--
I Should have said this much sooner but i didn't realise inputted values would change anything, or factor into anything of this
top of the code i have:

```
for num in numbers:
values.append(num)
```

with values being an empty list, and "numbers" is the Input

Comment: What is your desired output ? It's unclear from the above.

Comment: `20 * str(values[0])` gives `33333333333333333333` - is it output you want?

Comment: Bascially what i'm trying to do is have is my first value in the list multiplied by 20, and my second value in the list multiplied by 100,
eg: saying the value[0] to be 12 it would give me 240 as its is multiplied by 20

Comment: Wait, so do you want 60 or `[3,3,3,3,3,...,3,3,3]` (with 20 3s)?  "show up 20 times" and "multiplied by 20" are very different things.

Comment: `numbers = [3, 7]; multipliers = [20, 100]; multiplied = [i*j for i, j in zip(numbers, multipliers)]; print multiplied`?

Comment: @DSM i'm trying to get it to 60.

Comment: @ŁukaszR. Yeah exactly like that, only I would have no idea how to replicate that in a future project, where i'm planning to use everything i've learnt without looking at previous projects.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
>>> values = [3,7]
>>> n1 = 20 * [values[0]]
>>> n2 = 5 * [values[1]]
>>> print n1
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> print n2
[7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

number * list_value = product

```
In [1752]: values = [3, 7]

In [1753]: 20 * values[0]
Out[1753]: 60
```

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply by an `int`, the math functions take over. However, in order for repetition, just convert to a `str` then multiply:

```
n1 = 20*str(values[0])
n2 = 100*str(values[1])
print(n1,"\n",n2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of values and another list of numbers to multiply the corresponding values with:

```
values = [12, 14]
multiples = [20, 100]
```

Then, you can get what you want with:

```
result = [value * multiple for value, multiple in zip(values, multiples)]
```

See [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

If, on the other hand, you want to repeat the elements in `values` by the elements in `multiples`, you can do:

```
def repeat(values, repeats):
    for value, rep in zip(values, repeats):
        for _ in range(rep):
            yield value
```

Now, you can use `repeat()` as a generator to do what you want:

```
>>> list(repeat([3, 7], [5, 10])
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```